# how we use text to speech engine in a class which extends from Linear layout

Tags: android

Hi i want to convert string into speech in my code.i saw code for convert the text into speech in activity .But i want to use that text to speech in a class which is extends from LinearLayout.Actually i want to display one image according to that i want to spell that image name.for this purpose tell me some code  suggestions. Thanks in advance